# Deletar elemento do array

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

tenho um form com 60 input textbox com name numero[], desses 60 números só poderei selecionar uma quantidade x( quantidade pode ser variável ); como faço para quando o usuário desmarcar o checkbox o numero seja removido do array ?

```js
var i = 0,
  selecionados = [],
  maximo = {
    {
      $dados - > numeros
    }
  },
  input = 0;

Array.prototype.remove = function() {
  var what, a = arguments,
    L = a.length,
    ax;
  while (L && this.length) {
    what = a[--L];
    while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
      this.splice(ax, 1);
    }
  }
  return this;
};

//***************************************************************

function selecione(valor) {

  selecionados.push(valor);

  for (i = 1; i < selecionados.length; i++) {
    if (selecionados[valor] == valor) {
      selecionados.remove('' + valor);
      alert('ok');
      console.clear();
      console.log(selecionados);
    }
  }

  console.log(selecionados);

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form name="form" action="{{ route('aposta.salvar')}}" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="numeros" value="{{ $dados->numeros }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="cotacao" value="{{ $dados->cotacao }}"> @for ($i = 1; $i
    < 61; $i++) <div class="col-md-1">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="selecione({{$i}})" id="{{$i}}" name="numero[]" value="{{ ($i < 10) ? (0 . $i) : $i }}" />
      <div class="box box-primary checkbox" id="box-{{ $i }}" type="checkbox">
        <div class="box-body box-profile">
          <h5 class="text-center">{{ ($i
            < 10) ? (0 . $i) : $i }}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
@endfor

<div class="btn-inline">
  <a href="#" onClick="history.go(0)" class="btn btn-warning ">Limpar</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="gerar()" class="btn btn-danger">Gerar</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-flat">Proximo</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
var selecionados = [];
function selecione(item) {
  // Verifique se o item já existe no objeto "selecionados"
  let test = selecionados.filter(x => x === item);
  // Faça uma condição que verifica se o
  // número de elementos retornados é maior que 0
  // Se for remove o item, se não adiciona
  (test.length) ? selecionados.splice(selecionados.indexOf(item), 1) : selecionados.push(item);
  console.log('Selecionados: ', selecionados);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(1)" /> Item 1
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(2)" /> Item 2
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(3)" /> Item 3
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(4)" /> Item 4
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(5)" /> Item 5
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(6)" /> Item 6
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(7)" /> Item 7
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="selecione(8)" /> Item 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu suponho que você já tenha o índice do elemento que você quer remover, por causa desse trecho de código aqui:

```
if (selecionados[valor] == valor) {
```

Sendo assim, você só precisa dar um `splice` na array passando este mesmo valor no índice:

```
selecionados.splice(valor, 1);
```

Lembre-se que `splice` vai retornar o valor que foi removido de `selecionados` e `selecionados` vai ser modificado pelo `splice`.

Esse método `remove` que você está usando, pode até funcionar mas é desnecessário e pesado para o que você está fazendo.